# How to install R 3.4.4 in alpine

Tags: r, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I am trying to install R in my alpine image of docker. Earlier I did install it in my ubuntu image using

```
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9 \
  && add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/' \
  && apt-get update \ && apt-get install -y r-base
```

Nowhere I could find how to install it in alpine.
Any help would be appreciated.

My base image is python:3.7-alpine

Answer (score 7):

R is available in Alpine community repositories, so it's just a matter of installing the proper [package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.9/community/x86_64/R):

`apk add R`

For a more compact image you could start off a vanilla Alpine image, such as `alpine:3.9`, if you don't need Python specifically.

The latest R version available on Alpine is 3.5.1. The closest to 3.4.4 is 3.4.2, which is available in Alpine V3.7. In that case, start off Alpine V3.7:

```
$ docker run -it alpine:3.7 
/ # apk add R
```

If you need R version 3.4.4 exactly, you may have to build it from source. Fortunately, there is an excellent ready made Dockerfile by Artem Klevtsov which does just that:
https://github.com/artemklevtsov/r-alpine/blob/master/release/Dockerfile

Simply replace the R version string to 3.4.4 and build the image - works great.

**Edit:**

Another option for using a specific R version, which build is not available for native Alpine, is enabling [glibc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_C_Library) support on the Alpine container.

Normally, Alpine builds on [musl libc](https://www.musl-libc.org), which is a specialized [libc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library) implementation that is generally not compatible to glibc, which is the de-facto standard libc used by most other Linux distributions. With glibc installed, you should be able to run any general-purpose R Linux build on the Alpine container.

The following Dockerfile portion would enable glibc support, adding some 10MB to the Alpine container size:

```
# Based on: https://github.com/anapsix/docker-alpine-java
FROM alpine:3.7

ENV GLIBC_REPO=https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc
ENV GLIBC_VERSION=2.28-r0

RUN set -ex && \
    apk --update add libstdc++ curl ca-certificates && \
    for pkg in glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION} glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}; \
        do curl -sSL ${GLIBC_REPO}/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/${pkg}.apk -o /tmp/${pkg}.apk; done && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/*.apk && \
    rm -v /tmp/*.apk && \
    /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib
```

Comment: I dont want python specifically. I just want python 3 to be installed in my alpine image

Comment: @HarshitKhetan That's fine - so either start from a python image as you do now and install R on top, or install python on R based image - `apk add python3`

Comment: Sir I installed by using apk add R. And then I am installing rpy2 in my container.It's wheel is crashing. It seems like its not able to find R.

Comment: @HarshitKhetan hard to tell, but my best bet is that rpy2 requires R headers for building from source. Try adding the R dev package: `apk add R-dev`

Comment: This doesn't help if what we're after is a specific version of R

Comment: @MichaelChirico Indeed, only a subset of R versions are available for native Alpine. However, glibc could be enabled on Alpine in a simple procedure, adding some 10MB to image size: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57541576/7256341
Then, you could install any R version that is available for Linux.

Comment: @MichaelChirico I have updated my answer, accordingly.