# precompiled golang on alpine

Tags: docker, go, alpine-linux

I'm trying to write a dockerfile that uses alpine and takes advantage of a precompiled golang.

```
docker run -it  alpine:latest
```

```
wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.12.9.linux-amd64.tar.gz --no-check-certificate
tar -C /usr/local/ -xzf go1*.tar.gz
```

I'm getting /bin/sh/: ./go: not found

```
cd /usr/local/go/bin/
./go
```

It works fine on my ubuntu laptop so I'm unsure what the difference is here. I did a quick google and I could not find anything clear that points to something missing.

Comment: you seem to be in the wrong directory. perhaps `/usr/local/go/bin/` does not exist on the target machine?

Comment: yet I am able to pwd and ls -lah and see everything

Comment: is this related to glibc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Alpine is built using the [MUSL](https://www.musl-libc.org/) C library. You cannot run binaries that have been compiled for glibc in this environment. You would need to find a `go` binary built explicitly for the Alpine platform (e.g. by running `apk add go`).

Comment: `apk` has go version outdated by 2 years. It installs 1.13.15, while current is 1.16. `golang:alpine` image is the better choice.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `golang:alpine` base image for your `Dockerfile` (see available tags: https://hub.docker.com/_/golang):

```
FROM golang:alpine

RUN go version
```

or:

```sh
docker run -it golang:alpine /bin/sh
```

Answer (score 2):

As answered by larsks, Alpine will usually not run glibc built binaries, at least not out of the box.

However, there are cases in which the needed binary is not available, for example, the exact needed `go` build is not available for Alpine. Or, the case of Java (AdoptOpenJDK), where you need certified binaries, that are only available for glibc builds.

In these cases, you could create a glibc-enabled Alpine container:

```
# Based on: https://github.com/anapsix/docker-alpine-java
FROM alpine:latest

ENV GLIBC_REPO=https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc
ENV GLIBC_VERSION=2.28-r0

RUN set -ex && \
    apk --update add libstdc++ curl ca-certificates && \
    for pkg in glibc-${GLIBC_VERSION} glibc-bin-${GLIBC_VERSION}; \
        do curl -sSL ${GLIBC_REPO}/releases/download/${GLIBC_VERSION}/${pkg}.apk -o /tmp/${pkg}.apk; done && \
    apk add --allow-untrusted /tmp/*.apk && \
    rm -v /tmp/*.apk && \
    /usr/glibc-compat/sbin/ldconfig /lib /usr/glibc-compat/lib
```

`alpine-pkg-glibc` is a glibc custom built for Alpine (musl libc).
This procedures enables running glibc programs on your Alpine container.

Note, it does increase Alpine base image size - from 5.6MB to 16.5MB - but this seems a small price to pay for the desired compatibility in these cases, especially if the installed programs are themselves quite large.

Comment: can we build go binaries against glibc? how to do that?

Comment: @AbhijeetPadwal Using the mainstream glibc Linux go build, on glibc-enabled Alpine container (setup as above), might work